# Load timeout for module: domReady!_unnormalized2

Tags: google-chrome, requirejs, domready

How do you interpret this error?

> Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules:
>   domReady!_unnormalized2,domReady!_unnormalized3,domReady!

I'm using requirejs 2.1.2 and domReady 2.0.1.
It doesn't happen always, and apparently only in Chrome (in IE and firefox works fine).

I incremented the default load time with:

> require.config({ waitSeconds: 90 });

but it keeps failing.

Any Ideas? I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard amount of time that RequireJS will wait for a given `require()` call to complete; it allows some time for the relevant files to download. When using `domReady!`, the require call is forced to wait until the DOM is ready, which could be a longer period of time than require is willing to wait - resulting in the error you mention.

Ideally the DOM would not take so long to be ready, as that itself is an issue for the user experience, but in the case that it does, I believe we will have to avoid the `domReady!` dependency.